# zend framework Connect Error: could not find driver pdo mysql

Tags: zend-framework, pdo

I have a machine with:

- centOS 6.5
- php 5.5.7 from remi repository
- mysql 5.5.35 from remi repository

i'm triyng to connect zend framework 2 to a mysql database but i getting the following error:

---

An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException

File:

```
/var/www/zf2demo/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php:289
```

Message:

```
Connect Error: could not find driver
```

---

According to phpinfo i have the pdo installed and running

---

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

---

I already have the extensions pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so in my php.ini file.

my connection is done by (the username and password are at other file):

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=album;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: I already searched for a solution, but have not one yet.

Comment: You sure you've only got the one PHP install and it's the same one used by `phpinfo()` and your zf app?

Comment: Hi Phil! According to sudo find / -name php. I have /usr/bin/php and /usr/share/php 
/usr/lib64/php
/var/lib/php. I have write /usr/bin/php --version gives the same output as only php --version. The Apache Environment PATH is set to /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem at CentOS release 6.4 with Zend and PHP 5.4. PDO appears in phpinfo() but mentioned error ("could not find driver") ocurred on all pages related with database. Php 5.4 had included packages php-common, etc. and previous pdo package was obtained from alterantive yum/rpm repository. Maybe your current PDO package also fails.

Finally, in my case the solution was to install other php-pdo package (php54w-pdo.x86_64).

```
#yum install php54w-pdo.x86_64
```

I supose that you should install php55w-pdo.x86_64

```
#yum install php55w-pdo.x86_64
```

Don't forget restart Apache!

Comment: My problem was fixed by changing the user that access the DB. Mine was root and i was receiving these error.